# Как я могу считать цвет из пикселя в python

Tags: python

Допустим  есть сайт на котором расположены три прямоугольника.Как я могу узнать цвет и внести в переменные допусти даже через число (т.е. красный - 1 , зеленый - 2 , желтый - 3 )?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое «у есть на котором»? Сформулируйте вопрос нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
image = Image()
class Pixel:
    def __init__(self, position, color):
        self.position = position
        self.color = color

class Image:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_obj = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 100, 100)) # делаем скриншот
        self.pixels = self.image.load() # берем все пиксели

    def get_pixel(self, x, y):
        return Pixel((x, y), self.pixels[x, y])
```

Например:
`print(image.get_pixel(1, 1).color)` Вернёт цвет, условно, "255, 255, 255"