# Как считывать цвет конкретных пиксели с сайта,Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, color

Есть сайт, на котором расположены прямоугольники.

Нужно узнать их цвет и вывести в консоль как **`RGB`**.

---

Пример сайта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пример того, что должно получиться в консоли (оформление не имеет значения):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каковы точные входные данные?

Comment: Попробуйте делать скриншоты веб-страниц и затем с помощью pillow или других графических библиотек разбирать на пиксели. По скриншотам тут есть пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821285/python-Скриншот-веб-страницы-без-запуска-диалоговых-окон-браузера

Comment: а как брать цвет пикселей из фото можно тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071784/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-python/1071792#1071792

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как мне нравится все делать на PyQt5, то я вам и продемонстрирую
как бы я это сделал.

Если вы еще не устанонови PyQt5, то я очень рекомендую.

PyQt — реализация фреймворка Qt для языка Python.

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Теперь запускаем `python main.py`, нажимаем на пипетку и водим по экрану,
на консоль получаем результат.

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, Qt, QRectF, QLineF, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QFontDatabase, QFont, QPainter, 
                         QPainterPath, QColor, QPen)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget,
                             QDialog, QVBoxLayout)


FONT = b'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'


class ScaleWindow(QWidget):
    # Увеличенное окно просмотра
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScaleWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Tool | 
                            Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                            Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.resize(1, 1)
        self.move(1, 1)
        self._image = None

    def updateImage(self, pos, image):
        self._image = image
        self.resize(image.size())
        self.move(pos.x() + 10, pos.y() + 10)
        self.show()
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super(ScaleWindow, self).paintEvent(event)
        if self._image:
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            path = QPainterPath()
            radius = min(self.width(), self.height()) / 2
            path.addRoundedRect(QRectF(self.rect()), radius, radius)
            painter.setClipPath(path)
            # изображение
            painter.drawImage(self.rect(), self._image)

            # Средний синий перекрестие
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 174, 255), 3))
            hw = self.width() / 2
            hh = self.height() / 2
            painter.drawLines(
                QLineF(hw, 0, hw, self.height()),
                QLineF(0, hh, self.width(), hh)
            )

            # рамка
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 3))
            painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), radius, radius)


class CColorStraw(QPushButton):

    colorChanged = pyqtSignal(QColor)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CColorStraw, self).__init__(parent)

        # Загрузка шрифтов в библиотеку шрифтов
        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFontFromData(QByteArray.fromBase64(FONT))
        font = self.font() or QFont()
        font.setFamily('iconfont')
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setText('')
        self.setToolTip('Нарисуйте цвет экрана')
        self._scaleWindow = ScaleWindow()
        # Не забудьте сначала показать его, а затем спрятать. 
        self._scaleWindow.show()
        self._scaleWindow.hide()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._scaleWindow.close()
        super(CColorStraw, self).closeEvent(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(CColorStraw, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        # Установите стиль мыши на крест
        self.setCursor(Qt.CrossCursor)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(CColorStraw, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        # Установите стиль мыши на нормальный
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self._scaleWindow.hide()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(CColorStraw, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        # Получить положение мыши на экране
        pos = event.globalPos()
        # Возьмите часть увеличенного изображения
        image = QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(
            int(QApplication.desktop().winId()),
            pos.x() - 6, pos.y() - 6, 13, 13).toImage()
        color = image.pixelColor(6, 6)
        print(f'RGB color -> ({color.red()}, {color.green()}, {color.blue()})')
        if color.isValid():
            self.colorChanged.emit(color)
        self._scaleWindow.updateImage(pos, image.scaled(130, 130))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import cgitb
    sys.excepthook = cgitb.enable(1, None, 5, '')

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QDialog()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(w)
    view = CColorStraw(w)
    view.colorChanged.connect(lambda c: print(c.name()))
    layout.addWidget(view)
    w.exec_()
    QTimer.singleShot(200, app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]