# Рамки qss накладываются друг на друга

Tags: c++, qt, qss

При закруглении углов (наследуюсь от `QFrame`) рамки `qss` имеющие прозрачность накладываются друг на друга.

Код, отвечающий за рамки:

```
  setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFFFFF;"
            "border-style: solid;"
            "border-width: 13px;"
            "border-radius: 30px;"
            "border-color: rgba(123, 52, 251, 0.4);");
```

Избыточно жирные сделаны намеренно, чтобы лучше было видно проблему.

Как итог:

[image: Проблемные рамки qss]

Как лечить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    ...
    self.frame.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 13px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        
        border-color: rgba(193, 165, 244, 1);             /* <---- */  
    """)
    ....
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще, мне нужно именно прозрачность сохранить, в этом и цель (я уже приступил к реализации через paintEvent), но не могу не спросить - как вы так точно подобрали цвет?

Comment: @ff00000000x00, qss имеющие прозрачность накладываются друг на друга. Мой ответ был вам полезен?

Comment: S. Nick, да, вполне. Думаю, тогда придется от qss отказаться

Comment: @ff00000000x00, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084479/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-python/1084505#1084505